# Nested loops to report network groups, users and user details

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, nested

I have a script which is supposed to run and give the details of the groups and associated users and user's assigned details in a server.  I have 3 loops:

1. inside the first loop the "Net LocalGroup" command provides the list of **groups**.
2. the second loop in the line uses the result of parent loop as an input and fetches the number of **users** in each group
3. the third loop outputs **details** for each user, such as current login status and password expiry date

I have created the script below.  It runs, but does not give the output I want.

## script

```
@echo off
echo FID Name, Account Active, Account Expires, Password last set, Password expires, Password changeable, Password required, GlobalGroup
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%c in ('net localgroup^|findstr /b "*"') do (
set grp=%%~c
set grp=!grp:~1!
echo !grp!
PAUSE
for /f "tokens=1* delims=,"  %%x in ('net localgroup !grp!^|findstr /b "EUR"') do (
    set FID=%%~x
    set FID=!FID:EUR\=!
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a in ('net user !FID! /domain^|findstr /b "Account Global Password"') do (
        set FID1=!FID1!,%%a
        set FID1=!FID1:Global Group memberships=!
        set FID1=!FID1:Account active=!
        set FID1=!FID1:Account expires=!
        set FID1=!FID1:Password last set=!
        set FID1=!FID1:Password expires=!
        set FID1=!FID1:Password changeable=!
        set FID1=!FID1:Password required=!
        set FID1=!FID1: =!
    )
)
)
 echo !FID!%FID1%
```

### Actual output

```
FID Name, Account Active, Account Expires, Password last set, Password expires,Password changeable, Password required, GlobalGroup
The syntax of this command is:

NET USER
[username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
     username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
     username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
     username [/TIMES:{times | ALL}]

The syntax of this command is:

NET USER
[username [password | *] [options]] [/DOMAIN]
     username {password | *} /ADD [options] [/DOMAIN]
     username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN]
     username [/TIMES:{times | ALL}]

The syntax of this command is:

NET LOCALGROUP
[groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
          groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE}  [/DOMAIN]
          groupname name [...] {/ADD | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]

The syntax of this command is:

NET LOCALGROUP
[groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
          groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE}  [/DOMAIN]
Domain Users,Yes,Never,2014-11-1717:59:20,Never,2014-11-
1817:59:20,Yes,*EUR_Deny
InteractiveLo*cme_wsw_RLE_WRDC_Wint,Yes,Never,2013-05-1607:45:22,Never,2013-05-1
707:45:22,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0811:05:19,2013-11-0611:05:19,2013-
08-0911:05:19,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-0612:1
6:44,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-0612:16:44,Yes,
*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-11-2807:38:00,Never,2013-11-2907:38:00,Yes,*app_ldn_
was_Dat_Infra*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-0612:16:44,
Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-11-2807:38:00,Never,2013-11-2907:38:00,Yes,*app_
ldn_was_Dat_Infra*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-0612:16
:44,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2014-11-1717:59:20,Never,2014-11-1817:59:20,Yes,*
EUR_DenyInteractiveLo*cme_wsw_RLE_WRDC_Wint,Yes,Never,2013-07-0412:11:49,Never,2
013-07-0512:11:49,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-06
12:16:44,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-0612:16:44,
 Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-11-2807:38:00,Never,2013-11-2907:38:00,Yes,*app_
 ldn_was_Dat_Infra*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2011-03-3012:57:06,Never,2011-03-3112:57
 :06,Yes,*app_EUR_Standard_Inte*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,20
 13-08-0612:16:44,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-11-2807:38:00,Never,2013-11-290
 7:38:00,Yes,*app_ldn_was_Dat_Infra*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2012-04-3010:14:11,Neve
 r,2012-05-0110:14:11,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2008-05-2013:29:38,Never,2008-05
 -2113:29:38,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2010-01-2114:53:09,Never,2010-01-2214:53:
 09,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2011-07-1515:46:23,Never,2011-07-1615:46:23,Yes,*D
 omainUsers,Yes,Never,2010-05-2614:38:26,Never,2010-05-2714:38:26,Yes,*DomainUser
 s,Yes,Never,2011-12-2910:12:53,Never,2011-12-3010:12:53,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Nev
 er,2011-07-1510:15:57,Never,2011-07-
 1610:15:57,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2010-0
 1-1814:41:21,Never,2010-01-1914:41:21,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2011-08-1206:39
 :48,Never,2011-08-1306:39:48,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2011-06-1811:30:13,Never
 ,2011-06-1911:30:13,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2011-08-0512:25:30,Never,2011-08-
 0612:25:30,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2010-05-1814:18:06,Never,2010-05-1914:18:0
  6,Yes,*App_ldn_was_PER_Orbif*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-07-0412:11:49,Never,2013
 -07-0512:11:49,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-07-0412:11:49,Never,2013-07-0512:
 11:49,Yes,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-0612:16:44,Yes
 ,*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-07-0412:11:49,Never,2013-07-0512:11:49,Yes,*DomainU
 sers,Yes,Never,2013-11-2807:38:00,Never,2013-11-2907:38:00,Yes,*app_ldn_was_Dat_
 Infra*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-08-0512:16:44,Never,2013-08-0612:16:44,Yes,*Dom
 ainUsers,Yes,Never,2013-11-2807:38:00,Never,2013-11-2907:38:00,Yes,*app_ldn_was_
 Dat_Infra*DomainUsers,Yes,Never,2008-05-2013:29:38,Never,2008-05-2113:29:38,Yes,
 *DomainUsers
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Desired output

```
FID Name, Account Active, Account Expires, Password last set, Password expires,Password changeable, Password required, GlobalGroup
User1,Yes,Never,2008-05-2013:29:38,Never,2008-052113:29:38,Yes,*DomainUsers
User2,Yes,Never,2008-05-2013:29:38,Never,2008-052113:29:38,Yes,*DomainUsers
User3,Yes,Never,2008-05-2013:29:38,Never,2008-052113:29:38,Yes,*DomainUsers
User4,Yes,Never,2008-05-2013:29:38,Never,2008-052113:29:38,Yes,*DomainUsers
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Also if any duplicate user or blank group, i want to remove the same and want not to pick that and skip the same